# Using index from ForEach in other array

Tags: swift, swiftui

Why I can't use index from FromEach as index for other array. This index is Int, so what's the problem?

```
var word: String{
    return slova[selector]
}

var symbols: Array<Character>{
    return [Character](word)
}

var body: some View {
    HStack{
        ForEach(0..<word.count-1){index in
            Button("\(symbols[index])") {

            }

        }

    }
}
```

result: bug in "Button("(symbols[index])") {" :`Instance method 'appendInterpolation' requires that 'Character' conform to '_FormatSpecifiable'`

Comment: Use `String.init` instead of interpolation, so Replace `Button("(symbols[index])")` with `Button(String(self.symbols[index]))`

Answer (score 2):

The error is not due index, but about string generation, use instead

```
    ForEach(0..<word.count-1){index in
        Button(String(self.symbols[index])) { // << here !
```